# Does this many-to-many relationship make sense?

Tags: django, django-models

I'm writing a django app and I have the following models below, however I am unsure about the relatinonships of order_id and product_id in DetailedOrder and customer_id in Demand model.

In the DetailedOrder model, there can be multiple order_id (O0001) if the customer orders multiple product_id. Then the order_id can be used in the Order model to find who the customer was.

Or should the product_id in the DetailedOrder be a many to many relationship because there can be multiple products for 1 order_id - i think this makes more sense.

Also by this logic, does this mean customer_id in the Ordermodel should be a many-to-many relationship because there can be multiple customer_ids to multiple order_ids?

Any advice is appreciated!

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=150)
    customer_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True)

class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)


class DetailedOrder(models.Model):
    order_id = models.ForeignKey(Demand, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

## CSV data:

## Product csv:

```
product_id,product_name
P00001,TOOTHPASTE
P00002,SWEETS
P00003,CHOCOLATE
P00004,COMPUTER
P00005,LAPTOP
P00006,BRUSH
P00007,TOWEL
```

## Order csv:

order_id,customer_id

```
O00001,C00001
O00002,C00005
O00003,C00020
O00004,C00004
O00005,C00024
```

## Order Detail:

order_id,product_id,quantity

```
O00001,P00001,5
O00001,P00004,9
O00001,P00003,7
O00002,P00005,2
O00002,P00006,7
O00002,P00002,7
O00003,P00004,6
O00003,P00006,7
O00004,P00004,8
O00004,P00011,1
O00004,P00002,2
O00005,P00003,4
```

Comment: Your `DetailOrder` acts as the through model of a `ManyToManyField`. You can for the same `Order` have multiple `DetailedOrder`s, and thus also refer to multiple `Product`s.

Comment: that makes sense! so the order_id should be the many-to-many relationship? because then that will allow me access to the multiple products in detailedOrder?  ``` class DetailedOrder(models.Model):
    order_id = models.ManytoManyField(Demand, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    product_id = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()```

Comment: no. Your `DetailedOrder` is already the junction table, so it acts as what is a `ManyToManyField` doing. Therefore you should just use two `ForeignKey`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DetailOrder` acts as the through model of a `ManyToManyField`. You can for the same `Order` have multiple `DetailedOrder`s, and thus also refer to multiple `Product`s.

You can also span a [**`ManyToManyField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField) over this model to effectively find out the `Product`s, with `DetailedOrder` as the [**`through=…`** model <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through):

```
class Product(models.Model):
    product_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    product_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Order(models.Model):
    order_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
    customer_id = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(
        Product,
        through='DetailedOrder',
        related_name='orders'
    )

class DetailedOrder(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)
```

---

> **Note**: Normally one does not add a suffix `…_id` to a `ForeignKey` field, since Django
> will automatically add a "twin" field with an `…_id` suffix. Therefore it should
> be `product`, instead of <s>`product_id`</s>.

Comment: for the id.. does this mean customer_id should be changed to customer in Order model since I have a Customer model with customer_id already?

Comment: @RedRum: yes, you should rename it to `customer`, since a `ForeignKey` will fetch a `Customer` object, and not its id. If you rename it to `customer`, you can also use `.customer_id` to obtain the value of the primary key of the customer, so Django allows you to use `foo_id` if there is a `ForeignKey` named `foo`.

Comment: for anyone reading this, i've found this video explaining many-to-many using through. Really helps with understanding https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCfmSHzMcxw&ab_channel=IT_OF_WAHAM